# Add a unique ID to each menu item in Material UI TablePagination

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, accessibility

Is it possible to add a unique ID to each menu item that is rendered using `<TablePagination >`?

I want to add a unique ID (for example: `id="menu_item_0"`, `id="menu_item_1"` & `id="menu_item_2"`) to these (10, 25, 100) menu items, which are basically `<li>` tags.

[image]
[image]

Here's the code.

```
import * as React from "react";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Table from "@mui/material/Table";
import TableBody from "@mui/material/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@mui/material/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@mui/material/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@mui/material/TableHead";
import TablePagination from "@mui/material/TablePagination";
import TableRow from "@mui/material/TableRow";

const columns = [
  { id: "name", label: "Name", minWidth: 170 },
  { id: "code", label: "ISO\u00a0Code", minWidth: 100 },
  {
    id: "population",
    label: "Population",
    minWidth: 170,
    align: "right",
    format: (value) => value.toLocaleString("en-US")
  }
];

function createData(name, code, population, size) {
  const density = population / size;
  return { name, code, population, size, density };
}

const rows = [createData("India", "IN", 1324171354, 3287263)];

export default function StickyHeadTable() {
  const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(10);

  const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleChangeRowsPerPage = (event) => {
    setRowsPerPage(+event.target.value);
    setPage(0);
  };

  return (
    <Paper sx={{ width: "100%", overflow: "hidden" }}>
      <TableContainer sx={{ maxHeight: 440 }}>
        <Table stickyHeader aria-label="sticky table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              {columns.map((column) => (
                <TableCell
                  key={column.id}
                  align={column.align}
                  style={{ minWidth: column.minWidth }}
                >
                  {column.label}
                </TableCell>
              ))}
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {rows
              .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
              .map((row) => {
                return (
                  <TableRow hover role="checkbox" tabIndex={-1} key={row.code}>
                    {columns.map((column) => {
                      const value = row[column.id];
                      return (
                        <TableCell key={column.id} align={column.align}>
                          {column.format && typeof value === "number"
                            ? column.format(value)
                            : value}
                        </TableCell>
                      );
                    })}
                  </TableRow>
                );
              })}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
      <TablePagination
        rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 25, 100]}
        component="div"
        count={rows.length}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        onPageChange={handleChangePage}
        onRowsPerPageChange={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
      />
    </Paper>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit the-code-is-working-fine-in-codesandbox-but-showing-error-while-doing-in-the-id]

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you need the ID for? Maybe there are other means to achieve the same which need less code?

Comment: Did you take a look at the [`ActionsComponent` property](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/table-pagination/#props)? The API doc does not provide more details, but it sounds promising…

Comment: @Andy Do you have any idea how to use `ActionsComponent` ?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I don’t. Might be worth looking into it in your code editor. I don’t have a setup that would allow me quickly taking a look.
would you mind elaborating what you’d need the ID for?

Comment: For setup I already provided CodeSandbox link. And I'm planning to use the ID in unit test.

Comment: Oh, I didn’t realise you could actually navigate TS definitions in CodeSandbox. `ActionsComponent` is not related to your issue, sorry. It’s another Action button next to the select.
For your test don’t you have enough information already in the `<li>` elements to reference them? Like `data-value` for example?

Comment: I took a look at several properties of the TablePagination component, and couldn’t find anything that would allow to overwrite the option render or pass additional props down to the options. ):

Comment: Ok, no problem.

Comment: @Andy I found one solution for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`label` and `value` could be passed separately to `rowsPerPageOptions`

```js
rowsPerPageOptions={[
  {
    value: 10,
    label: <span id="menu_item_0">10</span>
  },
  {
    value: 25,
    label: <span id="menu_item_1">25</span>
  },
  {
    value: 100,
    label: <span id="menu_item_2">100</span>
  },
]}
```

Comment: I get this error:

Failed prop type: Invalid prop `rowsPerPageOptions[0]` supplied to `ForwardRef(TablePagination)`, expected one of type [number, string].